# jQuery .find() selects correct element but does not display it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase this question, so here's the details:

This little thing I've written up here: https://jsfiddle.net/f8thL83r/1/ 
works great, as long as you only want to show elements in the top menu.

Click on anything under "Graphic Design", and it won't display anything in the pane to the right. Why is it working for the first category and not the second?

Here's some code. I know the way I've done this is probably awful, but I'm just beginning to find my feet with jQuery.

```
$('#Menu h3').click(function () {
            $("#Menu ul ul").slideUp();
            if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }
        });

        $('#Menu ul ul li a').click(function (e) {
            var $currPage;
            e.preventDefault();
            $lastPage.hide();
            var j = ($(this).parent().index()); //index of the li to show
            var i = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index(); //index of the ul to show
            $currPage = $('#ServMain .list' + i).find('.page' + j);

            $currPage.show();
            $lastPage = $currPage;
        });
```

Comment: I mean a ul that's inside another ul. That isn't what the problem is. That has nothing to do with what the problem is. Go look at the fiddle.

Comment: You should stay away from cross-references like `$lastPage.hide();` in `click()` method

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't approach answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems other HTML elements of the selected page are not visible.
Below code should fix them

```
$('#Menu ul ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $lastPage.hide();
    var j = ($(this).parent().index());
    var i = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
    $('#ServMain ul').not('.list'+i).hide();
    $lastPage = $('#ServMain .list' + i).find('.page' + j);
    $lastPage.parent().show();
    $lastPage.show();
    $lastPage.find('div').show();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f8thL83r/5/)

Comment: Heh...yeah, I've worked it out so it does show all of the elements. I think what I really need to do is clean up that "onLoad" function at the beginning... there's just gotta be an easier way to do that...

Comment: Yes, it would be easier if only key elements are hidden. Also should add `e.preventDefault();` in the`$('#Menu h3').click(` block to prevent hash showing up in the URL.

Comment: After this, I'm going to have to find a way to make it so that when a user clicks on a navigation link in the actual nav menu, it'll bring them to this page, to this section, with their selection already opened up. I have a feeling that's going to be excruciatingly difficult considering my current design, but I don't even know. This is a real adventure for me.

Comment: It should not be that difficult as you can set and read a [parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/4454454) in the page URL

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the ul.list is hidden

```
$('#Menu ul ul li a').click(function (e) {
    var $currPage;
    e.preventDefault();
    $lastPage.hide();
    var j = ($(this).parent().index());
    var i = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
    $('#ServMain > ul').not('.list'+i).hide();
    $currPage = $('#ServMain .list' + i).show().find('.page' + j);
    $currPage.show();
    $lastPage = $currPage;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7w78p2y/)

Comment: Well, that sure does explain it. I'll get the hang of this eventually. Muchas gracias. Strange thing, though, it isn't showing the first li in the second category.